# Statically link a library that has newer platform SDK, possible?

Tags: c++, windows, sdk

I'm working with some ancient codebase that is being built with Visual C++ 6.0. I need to make a call to `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` but the platform SDK that it is being built with doesn't have that function defined (I guess it's some PSDK prior to 2000).

Updating the PSDK to one that does contain `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` doesn't seem like an option since Microsoft no longer offers support for Visual C++ 6.0 and the SDK's aren't available online (or even from purchasing a disc, I've tried).

My question is whether or not it's possible for me to write a static library in VS2010 that contains the `AllowSetForegroundWindow()` call, and link with VSC++ 6.0 project, and invoke the call through that library.

Or does anyone have a better idea to how I can work-around this problem in general? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GetProcAddress()` to wire a wrapper function to the real one at runtime:

```
BOOL WINAPI defaultAllowSetForegroundWindow( DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    SetLastError(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI shimAllowSetForegroundWindow( DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    static BOOL  (WINAPI *asfw)(DWORD) = 0;

    if (!asfw) {
        HMODULE user32 = LoadLibraryW(L"USER32");

        if (user32) {
            asfw = (BOOL (WINAPI *)(DWORD)) GetProcAddress( user32, "AllowSetForegroundWindow");
        }

        if (!asfw) {
            asfw = defaultAllowSetForegroundWindow;
        }
    }

    return (*asfw)(dwProcessId);
}
```

Your code can call `shimAllowSetForegroundWindow()` which will forward to the real API (or to a default that will fail gracefully on platforms that don't support the API).

You may need to customize to your needs for error handling or thread safety.